# How to update metadata about Trade Representative Contact Information using Fastlane/Deliver?

Tags: app-store, metadata, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I uploaded all the metadata to appstore including Screenshots, App review information , Rating and  all other things but unable to get any command to pass the Trade Representative Contact Information using Fastlane/Deliver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add in your Deliverfile something like this

```
trade_representative_contact_information(
  first_name: "Alex",
  last_name: "Kosyakov",
  address_line1: "Nevsky pr., 1",
  address_line2: "",
  address_line3: "",
  city_name: "Saint-Petersburg",
  state: "",
  country: "Russia",
  postal_code: "190000",
  phone_number: "+7921XXXXXXX",
  email_address: "blabal@gmail."
)
```

Comment: Worked for me, I added this in Deliverfile